# Protect hashicorp vault API token

Tags: security, devops

This is the scenario:

The client does not want the system administrator can access private data, so we are thinking to use hashicorp vault to save the master key used to encrypt data that will be saved in the database. But the application (NodeJS) needs to access the master key in order to decrypt and use the data, the application uses the hashicorp vault  API access token to do this.

The question is: What can we do in order only the application can read the API access token and not the administrator (root user)?.